# How to align messages in a RecyclerView depending on whether the user sent them

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, instant-messaging

I'm making a messaging app for school, I'm trying to make the messages coming from the user align to the right and the messages from others align left.

I've been looking online to try and figure out how to do it, but I don't understand any of them well enough to apply them. I was hoping for some help with applying any option to my app.

SubjectGroupPage.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_group_page);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.message);
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);


    rvMessagesSubjectGroupPage.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, true));
    final ArrayList<MessageObj> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<MessageObj> messagesAdap = readMessages(rvMessagesSubjectGroupPage, messages);
    MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(messagesAdap);
    rvMessagesSubjectGroupPage.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public ArrayList<MessageObj> readMessages(final RecyclerView rv, final ArrayList<MessageObj> messages) {

    db.collection("messagesIT")
            .orderBy("Timesent", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            String message = document.getString("Message");
                            String senderName = document.getString("SenderName");
                            String sender = document.getString("Sender");
                            Timestamp timesent = document.getTimestamp("Timesent");
                            MessageObj mess;
                            mess = new MessageObj(message, sender, senderName, timesent);
                            messages.add(mess);
                            Log.d(TAG, "mmmmm: " + mess.getMessage());
                            Log.d(TAG, "sssss: " + mess.getSender());
                            Log.d(TAG, "ttttt:" + mess.getTimesent());
                            showToast("b");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            showToast("There has been an error, please try again later.");
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e);

        }
    });

    return messages;
}
```

MessageAdapter.java

```
public class MessageAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<MessageObj> listdata;
private FirebaseAuth currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private boolean fromCurrentUser = true;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
private static String userObject = "";
private static final String TAG = "MessageAdapter.java";

public MessageAdapter(ArrayList<MessageObj> listdata) {
    this.listdata = listdata;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView sender;
    public TextView message;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.sender = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender);
        this.message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listLayout);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final MessageObj myListData = listdata.get(position);
    holder.sender.setText(listdata.get(position).getSenderName());
    holder.message.setText(listdata.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "click on item: " + myListData.getSender(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);

    TextView sender;
    TextView message;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listdata.size();
}


}
```

MessageObj.java

```
public class MessageObj {
private String message;
private String sender;
private String senderName;
private Timestamp timesent;
private boolean isCurrentUser;

public MessageObj() {}

public MessageObj(String message, String sender, String senderName, Timestamp timesent) {
    this.message = message;
    this.sender = sender;
    this.senderName = senderName;
    this.timesent = timesent;
}

public String getMessage() { return message; }

public String getSender() { return sender; }

public String getSenderName() { return senderName; }

public Timestamp getTimesent() { return timesent; }
```

Comment: check this https://blog.sendbird.com/android-chat-tutorial-building-a-messaging-ui

Comment: Should just be view location. Eg in ConstraintLayout you just set view to parent right or left.

Comment: You can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb) where this problem is actually solved.